# Require help to match a Regex pattern in c#

Tags: c#, regex

Please help me to match a **Regex** pattern which starts with the below format in C#:

> "Sec. 1.01."
>   "Sec. 47.06."
>   "Sec. 71.022."
>   "Sec. 611."
>   "Sec. 12A.002."
>   "Sec. 12A.152."
>   "Sec. 50D.001."
>
> "Sec. I.2."
>   "Sec. I.5B."

I've already tried `"Sec\.\s\d+\.\d+\."` but this works only for the pattern like 1st one in the above list.

Comment: Why does it only work on the first one? Can you show the exact code you’re using to find matches?

Comment: What are you exactly trying to do? Confirm that all those lines are correct? What would be a bad example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will match all of the examples you listed: `"Sec\. [A-Z\d]+\.([A-Z\d]+\.)?"\s?`

Notice: Only CAPITAL letters allowed with the Section number.

Explained demo here: http://regex101.com/r/hC7pP9

Answer (score 0):

Always in quotes, mix of numbers, letters and periods following 'Sec. ', one or more per line separated by a space?

("Sec.\s[\d\w.]+"\s?)+